# How to debug ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-pattern

I'm working on custom form validation for an Angular application using `ng-pattern`.

In my form I have:

```
<form name="jobsForm" id="jobs-form">
    <div jobs-form jobs="jobs">
        <div ng-form="jobsForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="source_path">Source Path:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="source_path" id="source_path" ng-model="jobs.source_path" ng-pattern="path_regex" required>
                <span class="input-error" ng-show="jobsForm.source_path.$invalid.pattern">INVALID PATH</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-red" ng-click="submitJob()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In my controller I define `path_regex`:

```
$scope.path_regex = /^[a-zA-Z]:\\(((?![<>:"\/\\|?*]).)+(\\)?)*$/;
```

When I try it out, nothing works.  What is the best way to debug this? Is it possible to put a breakpoint in and check my values for `ng-show`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure you can. If you look at the **angularJS** documentation for [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) and then click on the "**View Source**" button at top right, you will see the source code. There isn't much to this directive. Search for this code:

```
ctrl.$validators.pattern = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        // HTML5 pattern constraint validates the input value, so we validate the viewValue
        return ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue) || isUndefined(regexp) || regexp.test(viewValue);
};
```

So you can see there is a function being assigned to the array of **$validators** on the model controller. When data changes, all of the $validators will be executed.

Now go to the chrome debugger, **sources** panel and search for one of these lines of code and in your un-minified **angular.js** file. Put a breakpoint in this same function to make sure that your regex gets to the test.